# Meaning of 細い in 彼女は食が細い

Tags: meaning

> 彼女は食【しょく】が細い【ほそい】。
>   *She eats very little.*

Does 細い have that meaning in that context?

Answer (score 5):

If you search in the dictionary for a meaning of 細い that fits, you probably will not find any. 食が細い is an expression. And if you search for it in a dictionary like jisho as a whole, you will get the definition :

> eating only a little; having a small appetite

As a side note, 細い{こまい}, can mean stingy, so it might be funny to imagine someone being stingy with their food.

But your interpretation was the correct one.

Comment: Sorry to say but 細い is pronouced *hoso-i* not *koma-i*. *hoso-i *means thin, fine, slender, narrow, etc.

Comment: @mackygoo no need to feel sorry. but at least search in a dictionary before criticizing. Komai is another word with a different reading and meaning. And I am very aware of what hosoi is and means. The information about komai was only an educational side note. Not the answer.

Comment: There is no *furigana*s in the first line of your answer, so I gave the comment. I didn't intend to criticize the information of the side note at all. I should have said 細い is pronounced hoso-i not koma-i in the given sentence. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 細い　means thin. So yeah basically the amount she eats is very little.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the etymology of 食｛しょく｝が細{ほそ}い. But it sounds that the path to convey food to the stomach is narrow (細{ほそ}い) and the capacity of the stomach is small, so he/she eats a little and/or feels full soon, and as a matter of course he/she has a small appetite.

As for the antonym, you don't say 食｛しょく｝が太｛ふと｝い, but say like:
- 彼｛かれ｝は大｛おお｝食｛ぐ｝いだ。
- 彼｛かれ｝は大｛おお｝食｛ぐ｝らいだ。
- 彼｛かれ｝は大｛たい｝食｛しょく｝漢｛かん｝だ。